Looking at a new 4x4, just after some advice about the rear wheels
I'm about to get a new 4x4 which is the one in the image. The car is a 2016 Holden colorado with a 2" lift and then the mud tyres on that. The Person I'm thinking of buying it from is gonna get the Road Worthy Certificate. However I'm just wondering about the rear wheel set and that it is close to the guard at the back. It looks to me that the wheels are either too far forward or the flaps are in the wrong spot. Just wondering if I should be worried about this or not?
Any advice is welcome :)

I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be about vehicle maintenance or repair.

Unless you can easily move the forward guard the wheel will contact it on any small bump. I'd pass, personally. But also check clearances on the front, including full stop-to-stop steering.
